# How to get a highest mark from Avg mark table?

Tags: sql

```
%sql SELECT Sname,Sex,AVG(Mark) from record group by Sid
```

This code is try to avg all the student mark in one table, now I wanna get the highest fmale student makr in a table

Each student has 4 or 5 units only one Sid ID

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ORDER BY AVG(Mark) DESC` so as to have the highest mark first and then `LIMIT 1` to only get the first row returned.

```
SELECT 
  SID,
  Sname,
  Sex,
  AVG(Mark) AS average_mark
FROM
  record
WHERE 
  Sex = 'female'
GROUP BY
  SID,
  Sname,
  Sex
ORDER BY
  AVG(Mark) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thanks Kendle, that is good idea I also use DESC but did't thinking about LIMIT 1, this way is works, thanks so much